# How to print non-ascii characters to file in Python 2.7

Tags: javascript, python, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to obfuscate some javascript by altering their character codes, but I've found that I can't correctly print characters outside of a certain range, in Python 2.7.

For example, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
f = open('text.txt','w')
f.write(unichr(510).encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

I can't write unichr(510) because it says the ascii codec is out of range.  So I encode it with utf-8.  This turns a single character `u'\u01fe'` into two `'\xc7\xbe'`.

Now, in javascript, it's easy to get the symbol for the character code 510:

```
String.fromCharCode(510)
```

Gives the single character: Ǿ

What I'm getting with Python is two characters: Ç¾

If I pass those characters to javascript, I can't retrieve the original single character.

I know that it is possible to print the Ǿ character in python, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  I've gotten as far as using unichr() instead of chr(), and encoding it to 'utf-8', but I'm still coming up short.  I've also read that Python 3 has this functionality built-in to the chr() function.  But that won't help me.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this task?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you passing the `'\xc7\xbe'` to JavaScript?  Those two consecutive bytes (not to be confused with the characters Ç¾) are the UTF-8 encoding of Ǿ, which JavaScript should recognize as such (or at least treat no differently than a Ǿ appearing in a UTF-8 encoded JS file).

Comment: I'm saving the `'\xc7\xbe'` to a javascript file. Also, it is treating it as two separate characters. @jwodder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open the file in binary mode:

```
f = open('text.txt','wb')
```

And then write the bytes (in Python 3):

```
f.write(chr(510).encode('utf-8'))
```

Or in Python 2:

```
f.write(unichr(510).encode('utf-8'))
```

Finally, close the file

```
f.close()
```

Or you could do it in a better manner like this:

```
>>> f = open('e:\\text.txt','wt',encoding="utf-8")
>>> f.write(chr(510))
>>> f.close()
```

After that, you could read the file as:

```
>>> f = open('e:\\text.txt','rb')
>>> content = f.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> content
'Ǿ'
```

Or

```
>>> f = open('e:\\text.txt','rt',encoding='utf-8')
>>> f.read()
'Ǿ'
```

Tested on my Win7 and Python3. It should works with Python 2.X

Comment: Doesn't seem to change.  Still getting those two characters.

Comment: You should tell your text editor to open it in uft-8 encoding. But it works perfectly with my Win7+Python3.3+notepad(or UltraEdit).

Comment: looks like that might be the solution to the problem.  Hopefully it will port over to javascript as easily.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure to help you. I just tested it on my Win7+Python2.7. It also perfectly works. You can open it with notepad to check the result. It is possibly the problem of notepad++.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
import codecs
outfile = codecs.open(r"C:\temp\unichr.txt", mode='w', encoding="utf-8")
outfile.write(unichr(510))
outfile.close()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using python 2.7, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Python is writing the bytes `'\xc7\xbe'` to the file:

```
In [45]: unichr(510).encode('utf-8')
Out[45]: '\xc7\xbe'
```

JavaScript is apparently forming the unicode `u'\xc7\xbe'` instead:

```
In [46]: 'Ç¾'.decode('utf-8')
Out[46]: u'\xc7\xbe'

In [47]: 'Ç¾'.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')
Out[47]: '\xc7\xbe'
```

The problem is in how JavaScript is converting the bytes to unicode, not in how Python is writing the bytes.

Comment: The file is javascript. I'm decoding the js with a for loop, and adjusting each character with something like this: String.fromCharCode( l.charCodeAt(i) - 150 );

Comment: Also, I can see by viewing the file that Python is writing two characters when it should be writing one.

Comment: The for loop is intended to iterate over each character, so it is iterating over each byte, which is not what I want.

Comment: What single byte do you want written to the file? The choice has to range from `'\x00'` to `'\xff'` (256 choices).

Comment: I don't know @unutbu.  Believe it or not, I accidentally/somehow printed the Ǿ with python, but have no idea how I did it, and I'm trying to repeat my steps to no avail.

Comment: When you see `Ǿ` in a file, your editor is actually playing a trick on you. The file contains nothing but bytes. The editor chooses to decode those bytes using a codec, such as utf-8 or cp1252 or ascii, for example. The decoding associates byte sequences into characters with glyphs such as `Ǿ`. But the underlying file is still nothing but bytes. I don't know JavaScript, but if you can tell us what **bytes** are supposed to be in the JavaScript file, we can of course tell you how to write those bytes to a file in Python.

Comment: I think you're right.  The editor was playing a trick on me.  I'm able to toggle back and forth between those two characters by changing Notepad++'s from `UTF-8 without BOM` to `UTF-8`. Thanks for your help!