# Print characters for integer in any arbitrary encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can one perform the equivalent of the `chr()` function for any arbitrary encoding? Consider this attempt (doesn't work):

```
for i in range(128, 255):
    print("%s " % (i.encode('cp1252'),) )
```

This fails with `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`.

Neither does this attempt work:

```
for i in range(128, 255):
    j = "\x%x " % (i,)
    print("%x " % (j.encode('cp1252'),) )
```

This fails with `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape`.

I am specifically targeting Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? The second attempt comes down to this:

```
for i in range(128, 255):
    j = chr(i)
    print("%x " % (j.encode('cp1252'),) )
```

But I don't see how that's the equivalent of `chr` for cp1252. `chr(i)` converts from the position `i` in the code page to the corresponding character (the return value is a unicode string of length 1). You can do a similar conversion for cp1252 (or any other encoding), using
`bytes([i]).decode('cp1252')`, which looks more like your first attempt.

Comment: I had to decode `j` and print it as a string, but this worked. `print("%s " % (j.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1252'), ))`. Note also that code points 128-159 would not work, I had to start at 160. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, I believe you want this,

```
chr(i).encode('cp1252')
```

or in Python 2.x, you would use,

```
unichr(i).encode('cp1252')
```

Full code is,

```
for i in range(128, 255):
    print("%s " % (unichr(i).encode('cp1252',errors='replace')))
```

On my console, the `cp1252` encoding does not work and throws an exception. To at least print a hex value, you can include the `errors` part.

This post is relevant: [Python 3: Demystifying encode and decode methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469591/python-3-demystifying-encode-and-decode-methods) and [How to print non-ascii characters to file in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869825/how-to-print-non-ascii-characters-to-file-in-python-2-7)

Comment: And not with 3.3 either.

Comment: Of course I tried it. When you say 'not working' can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Looping through `range(128, 255)` throws a `UnicodeDecodeError` in the first character